# Vim in Gnome-terminal says “Output is not to a terminal”

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

I have several reasons to think that my terminal behaves like a console.

I use GNOME Terminal 3.18.3.

When I open vim from my terminal on fedora 23, the following warning is emitted: "Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal".

When I open the manual for a command, it does not switch the terminal in "reading" mode.
What I mean by that is that it does not put me on the manual page where I could scroll using HJKL and quit using q.
Instead, it just prints the content of the manual as the result of a command like ls in one fell swoop.

Commands like ls are not colored.

I think this happened after I tried using my computer using Ctrl+Alt+F3 (from the console).

How can I set my terminal back to its previous state?

Comment: A console interface is a terminal so to understand your problem, please specify **how** you access it.

Comment: I use GNOME Terminal, the default graphical terminal of fedora. I launched it from the graphical interface.

Comment: @MMCXCVII 2197?

Comment: @andy256 something you `<<8`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are likely (attempting) to redirect the output of your shell to a file, e.g., something like

```
bash -i | tee foo
$ vim
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

While you can *read* (most) commands from the keyboard via that approach, the *output* is no longer a terminal.  You can recover by closing that shell and capturing output in a different way: the `script` command can capture output sent to a terminal without interfering with it.  For example

```
script -c bash foo
```

will write *all* of the text sent to the terminal while running that `bash` command, and the output will still be a terminal (rather than a pipe or a file).

Further reading:

- [script - make typescript of terminal session](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html)

Comment: Where is the redirection supposed to be? I checked the file .bashrc and .bash_profile and did not see any mention of the redirection you mentioned. Also, it might be useful for you to know that when I login from the console (using Ctrl+Alt+F3), the following appears: `-bash: sh/zsh: No such file or directory`

Comment: And when I open a terminal window, before anything the following appears: `cat: /tmp/x: No such file or directory`

Comment: That is likely in your .bashrc or files that it sources.  If you are unsure about that, you could rename your .bashrc file temporarily, and open a new window.

Comment: Thank you very much, I renamed .bashrc and .bash_profile and all the warnings have been removed. In addition, I can see manual pages normally. I will remove the lines of code I am unsure of one by one to see which one was the cause.

Comment: Great solution, is there any way to separate output for `stdout` and `stderr`?